# Changing field delimiter and quoting character

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I would like to modify the content of 2 different files. How can I obtain the expected output by using a generic script in unix?

1st file:
`"` inside quoted string,
`"` and `,` (separator) inside quoted string

example:

```
"20181115","12345643","This is a "test"","","657","This is a "TEST"","","aaaa"
"20181115","12345632","This is an "example" of the file, a "sample" aaaa","123","",""TEST"","",""
```

**expected output:**

```
~20181115~;~12345643~;~This is a "test"~;~~;~657~;~This is a "TEST"~;~~;~aaaa~
~20181115~;~12345632~;~This is an "example" of the file, a "sample" aaaa~;~123~;~~;~"TEST"~;~~;~~
```

2nd file:
`|` (separator) inside quoted string and multiple `"` inside the string

example:

```
"098789"|"Hello world!"| 12,7|"Cities I want to visit Rome| London"|15.11.2018|"Yes"
"032425"|"Travel in ""New York"", USA"| 113,3||15.11.2018|"Yes"
```

**expected output:**

```
~098789~;~Hello world!~; 12,7;~Cities I want to visit Rome| London~;15.11.2018;~Yes~
~032425~;~Travel in /"New York/", USA~; 113,3;;15.11.2018;~Yes~
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the input data is not standard CSV.  A double quoted string at the very start or end of a double quoted field should look like `""test""`, i.e., `"This is a ""test"""`.  Therefore, thes _simple_ solution of using a CSV parser will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try simple `sed` substitutions for your first problem:

```
sed 's/","/~;~/g; s/^"\|"$/~/g' file
```

and a more involved `awk` script for your second:

```
awk -F\" '{$1=$1; for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) gsub ("\|", SUBSEP, $i); gsub ("\|", ";"); gsub ("~~", "/\""); gsub (SUBSEP, "|")} 1' OFS="~" file
```

It first replaces all `|` within double quotes with an unusual placeholder not commonly found in text files, then does the desired replacements, then reverses the placeholder substitution.

Please be aware that both are taylored to your problems and thus not generally applicable to other, even similar, problems without adaption.

Output if applied to sample in your question (Ubuntu, mawk 1.3.3 Nov 1996):

```
~098789~;~Hello world!~; 12,7;~Cities I want to visit Rome| London~;15.11.2018;~Yes~
~032425~;~Travel in /"New York/", USA~; 113,3;;15.11.2018;~Yes~
```

Comment: I have a question regarding the awk (for second case: the separator is added after each letter and not after each word

Comment: ;~;|;0;|;9;|;8;|;7;|;8;|;9;|;~;|;~;|;H;|;e;|;l;|;l;|;o;|; ;|;w;|;o;|;r;|;l;|;d;|;!;|;~;|; ;1;2;,;7;|;~;|;C;|;i;|;t;|;i;|;e;|;s;|; ;|;I;|; ;|;w;|;a;|;n;|;t;|; ;|;t;|;o;|; ;|;v;|;i;|;s;|;i;|;t;|; ;|;R;|;o;|;m;|;e;|;|;|; ;|;L;|;o;|;n;|;d;|;o;|;n;|;~;|;1;5;.;1;1;.;2;0;1;8;|;~;|;Y;|;e;|;s;|;~;
;~;|;0;|;3;|;2;|;4;|;2;|;5;|;~;|;~;|;T;|;r;|;a;|;v;|;e;|;l;|; ;|;i;|;n;|; ;|;~;~;|;N;|;e;|;w;|; ;|;Y;|;o;|;r;|;k;|;~;~;|;,;|; ;|;U;|;S;|;A;|;~;|; ;1;1;3;,;3;|;|;1;5;.;1;1;.;2;0;1;8;|;~;|;Y;|;e;|;s;|;~;

Comment: Not for me; see output that I added to the answer. Did you copy the proposal one-to-one, char by char? What be your `awk` version? Something strange with your input?

Comment: the version is GNU Awk 3.1.7